# What is this pod at the wing-tip of a U2?

Tags: military, wing, sensors

In this image of a U2S, what it the very unaerodynamic looking pod at the wing-tip? It looks like it holds some sort of sensor package. However, it doesn't seem to appear on all U2s (at least not based on photos on Wiki).

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Lockheed_U-2_TR-1B.jpg]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2)</sup>

Comment: I believe it's part of/an attach point for the landing skids. That may not be the only use, however, so I'll pass on leaving this as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pod contains the Radar Warning Reciever (RWR). The variant in the picture is the TR-1B, which had wingtip mounted RWR units. According to [globalsecurity.org](http://www.globalsecurity.org/intell/systems/u-2-variants.htm):

> The Air Force has fielded new electronic countermeasures on the aircraft, giving it a jamming capability and upgraded radar warning equipment with wing-tip mounted digital receivers.

As an another exmaple, SAAB seems to have put [RWR on the wingtips of Gripen](http://saab.com/globalassets/commercial/air/electronic-warfare/radar-warning-receivers/bow/bow-product-sheet.pdf), though the equipment are certainly different (U-2 uses [AN/ALQ variants](http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20051020005396/en/BAE-SYSTEMS-Advanced-Defensive-System-Deployed-U-2)).

Note that the bottom of the 'pod' has (wingtip) landing skid at the bottom and navigation light on the side. The RWRs face outside at an angle of ~45$^{\circ}$. This (containing RWR, skid and nav lights in a single package) is a later design and was added to the exiting U-2Rs as retrofit. It was not avialble in the earlier models.

Comment: Your AN/ALQ link seems quite rather broken.

Comment: @FreeMan Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

In [here](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/90464main_ER2handbook.pdf) you can find the handbook of the "civil" version on the U2, the ER-2 by NASA. Researching here and there it seems to be a "pod". In particular from the document above:

> Other payload areas that have been used in the past, including the
>   wing tips, [...]  can  support  small  instrument  assemblies. The
>   structural and electrical connections for these non-standard installa-
>   tions require individual consideration. Contact Lockheed Engineer-
>   ing  for  attachment  details  if  you  are  considering  one  of  these
>   locations.

What is inside it depends on the versions.

According to [this document](http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1996/0276/report.pdf) in the 90s they were proposing the wing tip to install potassium magnetometers to make high altitude magnetometric measurements ove Alaska.

According to [this site](http://www.clubhyper.com/reference/u2sdwa_1.htm) it is a pod used for Electronic Counter Measures ([ECM](http://hsfeatures.com/features04/u2sdwa_2.htm)).

The ECM has been upgraded in 2005, but from the photos on Airliners.net it seems to be there since before 2005.